# Print Urdu in python using utf-8

Tags: python, printing, utf-8, urdu

I have a csv file in which I stored data in using  utf-8 
now when I open my csv file with this commmand

```
            with open('alkhidmat.csv', newline='',encoding = "ISO-8859-1") as f:
                reader = DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
                for row in reader:
                                name = row['Person Name']
```

it prints

```
Ø§Ø³Ø§Ù
```

original string which is store in csv file is

```
اسامہ
```

Comment: why are you passing the encoding as `"ISO-8859-1"` when you say it is utf-8???

Comment: because when I again use utf-8 it gives me unicode mapping error

Comment: Then it isn't utf-8.